# Vite | Could not resolve entry module (chroootwww/index.html)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I have problem. At command line I do `npm run build` and result is:

```
ondrej@vostro-ov:/mnt/web_x1/aou511/chrootwww$ npm run build

> vue@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v3.1.0 building for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
Could not resolve entry module (chroootwww/index.html).
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve entry module (chroootwww/index.html).
    at error (file:///mnt/web_x1/aou511/chrootwww/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///mnt/web_x1/aou511/chrootwww/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22369:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

File **vite.config.js is**:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }, 
  root: 'chroootwww/',
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    outDir: 'www/dist', 
  },
})
```

File *index.html* exist
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is, please?
Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: The problem not finding `chroootwww/index.html` may be because you have in your config file `chroootwww`? What if you change it to the actual path of the file?

Comment: `chroootwww` ... `chrootwww` - can you see any difference?when you do spot the difference, you'll say "ooo"

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález When index.html move to others folder the problem disappears

Comment: @JaromandaX typing error corrected, but problem is not resolved

Comment: so it's still saying that `Could not resolve entry module (chroootwww/index.html)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, still the same error message

Comment: If use command `npm run dev` answer is `Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
`

Comment: So the error still has 3 o's?

Comment: No `Could not resolve entry module (chrootwww/index.html)`

Comment: Ok, lets see if you get this now xD: Where is the index.html file located relative to your folder? Is inside that chroootwww route or it is _somewhere else_? Remember the "realtive to".

Comment: File index.html is located in the 'chrootwww' folder. I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting